# I think my question got mistakenly marked as a duplicate, help?

Tags: support, duplicates

In order to help explain the difference between Ubuntu, its flavors, unofficial remixes, and unofficial derivatives, I created a self answered question called "[Ubuntu, Ubuntu Flavors, Ubuntu Remixes, Ubuntu Derivatives - what's the difference?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422818/ubuntu-ubuntu-flavors-ubuntu-remixes-ubuntu-derivatives-whats-the-differen?noredirect=1#comment2477005_1422818)" In the answer, I give a clear, concise explanation as to what the four things are and what the difference is between them, including the technical rationale behind why remixes and unofficial derivatives are not officially supported by the Ubuntu community.

Sadly I'm guessing I chose the perfectly wrong title, as my question got flagged as a duplicate of two loosely related questions that mostly missed the point of my original question, but that appeared to be duplicates looking at the title.

One was [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives). While this sounds like a duplicate, it actually dives deep into the differences between the official Ubuntu flavors (like the fact that Kubuntu uses the KDE desktop rather than Unity or GNOME), which wasn't the point of my question at all.

The other one was was [What does "official Ubuntu flavour" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699354/what-does-official-ubuntu-flavour-mean). This answers only one aspect of my question, and while it answers that aspect very well and in great detail, it completely leaves out the other three aspects of the question.

Is this question actually a duplicate of the two linked questions? If so, can someone explain to me why? If not, could we throw some reopen votes at my question?

Comment: I think you've made a good argument, and your post already has more votes than the "duplicate" 6 year old topic [What does "official Ubuntu flavour" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699354/what-does-official-ubuntu-flavour-mean) I've voted to reopen.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your posts with additional layout, details, links etc. Use whatever you see fit, or suggest corrections yourself, which I'll happily apply.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Wow, I love what you did to it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you - I did the same for the question. Again, anyone please feel free to improve. I tried to add a bit more detail and make it easily readable. 

Comment: I actually feel this Q&A should somehow be part of the Help Center, as it gives a very good understanding of the relation between different Ubuntu releases and their support status. Very helpful to new and experienced users alike. 

Comment: Good to see a great question and answer survive the Close Votes gauntlet!